# AKS primality test lower bound

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, primality-test

In [this paper](http://cr.yp.to/papers/aks-20030125-retypeset20220327.pdf), in the first part of Section 7, D.J. Bernstein mentions that the original AKS paper ([Lemma 4.4 and its proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20030916043235/http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/news/primality.pdf)) uses an extremely crude lower bound for the number of elements in $G$ (as it is defined in the original AKS paper). Bernstein gives the bound ${|T| + \deg h - 1 \choose |T|}$, which (barring the `$+1$' for the zero polynomial) is the same as the original AKS paper (which states ${l+d-1 \choose l}$, where $l$ equals $|T|$ and $d$ equals $\deg h$).

So the original AKS paper gives the same exact count for the number of elements in $G$. Why does Bernstein refer to the bound in the original AKS paper being crude? Or does he refer to the 'crude bound' being $(\frac{d}{l})^l$ as the bound for the binomial coefficient? If so, I don't exactly see how Bernsteins discussion in this part determines a better/exact lower bound on $G$.

Thanks in advance for any clarification.